# Shopware 6: Creating Child-Theme / Extending Theme SOLVED

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want to extend the following theme: https://store.shopware.com/zenit10712681513/theme-gravity-pro-responsive-premium-template.html?c=1033

In theme.json of my child-theme I put the theme right below @storefront. My child-theme inherits only the css-values and not the templates, though.

Here is what my theme.json looks like:

```
  "name": "ChildTheme",
  "author": "nix",
  "views": [
     "@Storefront",
     "@zenitPlatformGravity",
     "@Plugins",
     "@ChildTheme"
  ],
  "style": [
    "app/storefront/src/scss/overrides.scss",
    "@Storefront",
    "@zenitPlatformGravity",
    "app/storefront/src/scss/base.scss"
  ],
  "script": [
    "@Storefront",
    "@zenitPlatformGravity",
    "app/storefront/dist/storefront/js/child-theme.js"
  ],
  "asset": [
    "@Storefront",
    "@zenitPlatformGravity",
    "app/storefront/src/assets"
  ],
  "configInheritance": [
      "@Storefront",
      "@zenitPlatformGravity"
  ]
}
```

Can anyone tell me if there is something missing?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin provider supplys a skeleton for child-themes which I'm using now